# How to upload user's contact data to HoundServer using Houndify python SDK

Tags: python, sdk, houndify

I want to upload my contact data to Hound Server.
Cloud you show me how to do it?

I want to try Phone Domain, but I caught following error.

> Call john
>   "Contact information is not available until it is synchronized with the Hound cloud."

I set RequestInfo UseContact data = true using python SDK,
https://docs.houndify.com/reference/RequestInfo

But I can not upload user's contacts (OneContact(Firstname, PhonEntries...) to HoundServer.
https://docs.houndify.com/reference/OneContact

Could you show me how to do it?